# Is the ring of formal power series a localization of some non local ring at prime ideals?

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, localization, formal-power-series, local-rings

Consider $F = K[[x]],$ the formal series over field $K.$ We know that $K$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $(x).$ Does there exist a non local ring $R$ and prime ideal $p$ such that $R_p =  K[[x]]?$  Since $(x)$ is the only prime ideal in $F,$ $p$ should be minimal prime ideal in $R.$ I tried to polynomia ring $R=K[x]$ with $p=(x)$ the corresponding localisation will not be $F.$ I am not able to find an example or show that no such $R$ exist.

Comment: What about $R=K[[x]]$ and $p=(x)$?

Comment: That would be trivial, I forgot to mention that $R$ should be nonlocal.

Comment: That's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: There are still trivial exceptions: e.g. $R = K[[x]] \times S$ for any ring $S$ is never local, and has $K[[x]]$ as a localization. Maybe what you're looking for is: if $K$ is countable, any localization of a finitely generated $K$-algebra has countable dimension as a $K$-vector space, but $K[[x]]$ has uncountable dimension